# Making a Link Appear if a Condition is Met

Tags: javascript

The PHP code below echoes a link if the "loginid" of the logged-in user is on a list determined by getEditorList();.  It works fairly well, but I think it might work better if I were to do it with Javascript instead.

How could I accomplish the same thing with Javascript?

Thanks in advance,

John

```
$editors = getEditorsList();
            foreach($editors as $editor)
            {
            $editorids[] = $editor['loginid'];
            }

            if(in_array($_SESSION['loginid'], $editorids))
            {
            echo "<div class='footervote'><a href='http://www...com/.../footervote.php'>Vote</a></div>";
            }
```

Login function:

```
<?php
if (!isLoggedIn())
{

    if (isset($_POST['cmdlogin']))
    {

        if (checkLogin($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']))
        {
            show_userbox();


        } else
        {
            echo "Incorrect Login information !";
            show_loginform();
        }
    } else
    {

        show_loginform();
    }

} else
{

    show_userbox();

}



?>
```

Comment: Keep it in PHP. If you were to do it with JavaScript, you would have the make the result of `getEditorList()` and `loginid` public. This is because JavaScript is a client side language; PHP of course, is server side.

Comment: What exactly is that condition? It seems to be a purely server-side thing. You could of course use PHP to write a JS variable and then show or hide the link depending on that, instead of writing the link directly. But whats the point other than making your page unnecessarily depended on JavaScript?

Comment: Basically, the PHP condition only works when I refresh the browser a few times.  I want it to work the first time.  Others have advised me to use Javascript so this won't happen, but I guess this might not be good advice.

Comment: That sounds like that you have a caching problem. It would be better to find a solution for that instead.

Answer (score 0):

So actually, your problem is "After a user logs in, he often still gets the non-logged in version of the pages", and you propose the "Make the link appear in Javascript" as a solution. Then you ask how to do that :)

RoToRa already pointed out that the cause of your problem probably has to do with the **browser cashing the pages**, and not requesting a new page after the user has logged in, but showing the old page from cache. There are several solutions for this, even with Javascript.

To avoid caching:

- Add a '**Pragma: No-Cache**' header to your page.
- Add a '**Expires: -1**' header to your page.
- Use the **Cache-Control** HTTP headers from HTTP 1.1

Check the [PHP header function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) for more information how to do that in PHP, or read your webservers documentation.

Another possible solution is to have the page serve as **static**, and then **use AJAX** to check if the user is logged-in, and if so, load the custom content for that user. Typically you'll create an extra php-script to check if the user is logged in, and have the AJAX call this script. This is quite easy to do using a decent Javascript library like jQuery, but you can do it without libraries should you really need to do so.

Checkout [PHP JSON](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php), [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) for more info about those solutions.

A last often (ab)used solution is to have a **query string** for your page - browsers will see the query string is different, and won't cache the page.